transform list of numbers using Synchrosqueezing transformer
I want to transform a list of numbers using Synchrosqueezing transformer :
The problem is I want convert this list "t" by "ssq_cwt(xo)"  to another list with same lentgh.
import numpy as np
from array import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ssqueezepy import ssq_cwt, ssq_stft

#%%# Define signal ####################################
N = 8
t = [1, 7, 0, 6,1, 9, 0, 5]
t = np.asarray(t)
xo = np.cos(2 * np.pi * 2 * (np.exp(t / 2.2) - 1))
xo += xo[::-1]  # add self reflected
x = xo + np.sqrt(2) * np.random.randn(N)

#%%# CWT + SSQ CWT ####################################
Twxo, Wxo, *_ = ssq_cwt(xo)


ssq_cwt doesn't do that.  It produces an array of values based on the number of frequencies and number of timeshifts.  Perhaps you wanted some other function.
